# Calculate the probability that the needle crosses at least one of the lines when tossed at random on the floor: for $\alpha$ = 45

Tags: probability

A floor is ruled with equally spaced parallel lines. A needle is such that if its two ends are placed on adjacent lines the angle between the needle and the lines is α  where 0 ≤ α ≤ $\pi$/2. Calculate the probability that the needle crosses at least one of the lines when tossed at random on the floor:

a) for $\alpha$ = 45

b) for a general $\alpha$ between 0 and $\pi$/2

Comment: This is the [Buffon's needle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem)

Comment: You probably mean $\frac\pi4$ where you wrote $45$?